# Unable to change listview color onPostExecute of Async Task

Tags: android-asynctask

I am unable to change the color of a listview item in the Async Task onPostExecute

```
final int color = 0xAA8D75B0;

private class ClientAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 // some code here ...
 protected void onPostExecute(String res) {

 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, mylist);
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);

 int n = lv.getCount();
 for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    lv.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(color);
 }
}
```

I got null pointer exception at runtime. However when i try to change the color inside a button onClickListener, it works fine. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
Runnable color = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
        your code to change color here
        ...
    }
};
lv.postDelayed(color, 1000);
```

Comment: This code works initially, but when the item number is more than 10, I get null pointer exception again.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your code in the ui-thread to avoid a nullpointerexception. So just try this and it will solve your problem (assuming your AsyncTask is a inner class of an Activity):

```
private class ClientAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
// some code here ...
protected void onPostExecute(String res) {

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, mylist);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    int n = lv.getCount();
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                lv.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(color);
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code is not working. I think if it is inside doInBackground, then only you need runOnUiThread right?